# Unexpected decorator behavior, "if" statement executes after if 1==2:

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, decorator, python-decorators

А few hours ago I submitted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003962/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-when-applying-decorator-to-generato?noredirect=1#comment94845337_54003962) and got an answer why I need to add `yield` to my decorator in order to function properly. 
I have lately recalled that I had omitted it for a reason - a strange behavior I can not explain.

I apologize in advance if I am blind, but I spent hours staring at and playing with this code and this is what I get:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 1==2:
            print ("Generator")
            for item in func(*args, **kwargs):
                print(item)
                #yield(item)
        else:
            print ("Not generator")
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print(res)
            return res
    return wrapper

@decor            
def f():
    return "a"


f()

"""
Output:
    Not generator
    a

"""
```

And if I remove the comment before `yield` there is no output at all.

Why is that? And how is it possible that anything which I change within a `if 1==2:` statement takes any effect on the script?

Comment: Are the numbers 1 and 2 in Python by any chance floating point numbers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey nope, they are good old ints unless written as 1.0 and so on. No floating point issues here.

Comment: Your `wrapper` cannot be both a normal function and a generator function. Conditionally define a wrapper as a generator or a normal function and return that. A yield *anywhere* in the function definition automatically makes the whole thing a generator. This happens at function definition time

Comment: No repro: https://repl.it/repls/PutridShinyProfessionals

Comment: @RobertHarvey When I visit that link and hit "run", I get exactly the output the OP reported. When I uncomment `yield` I get an error, which is probably what the OP intended to ask about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which is that the `if` block never executes, exactly as you would expect?

Comment: @Robert Which is that the script errors out entirely when a `yield` is present in that function, even when it can't be reached. The latter surprises the OP; the former seems to have been unknown by both you and me until now :) It would be nice if the answer covered both aspects.

Comment: Oh.  Well, I didn't check that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's certainly not the clearest question I've seen today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function contains `yield` *anywhere* in the body, it is a generator function. It does not matter if the `yield` is executed or not. The fact that `1 == 2` is false has nothing to do with it.

Consider the following function:

```
def addone(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        yield number + 1
```

What happens when you call `addone([])`? The `yield` is never executed, and yet `addone` still returns a generator. Why should this be any different:

```
def addone(numbers):
    if numbers:
        for number in numbers:
            yield number + 1
```

So it becomes clear that whether or not the `yield` is actually executed is not relevant. The only relevant fact is whether the `yield` exists in the body of the function.

### How to fix the function

The fix is relatively simple, all you have to do is pull the part with the `yield` into a separate function:

```
import types

def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
        print("Is a generator")
        return wrap_generator(result)
    print("Not a generator")
    return result

def wrap_generator(gen):
    for item in gen:
        print(item)
        yield item
```

### How to avoid in the future

In general, the problem here is that a function is either a generator (and uses `yield`) or is a normal function (and uses `return`). It is a bit confusing when you use both `yield` and `return` in the same function!

For Python, it turns out that if you use both `yield` and `return` in the same function, the function is a generator function. This may be somewhat confusing, so as a matter of style, I would generally avoid using both `return` and `yield` in the same function.

Comment: I see that the Pythonistas understand what you've said, but I don't get it at all.  Why would a `yield` in a code block that never executes have any effect at all on any code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Dont worry, do you know about generators in python? its...a thing that you dont really need to learn about when starting with python. But this question and the yield statement revolve around it.

Comment: I think the key point is that the OP failed to report that the script errors out when the generator returns with argument, and so it's hard to know why this answer is relevant/correct (which it is) -- that making the whole thing a generator was [apparently] not deliberate. And those of us who are not Pythonistas would not necessarily have been aware that such a thing is an error. As such, a bit of clarification may be useful here: slightly too much prior knowledge assumed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: How could Python possibly know whether a code block will execute before it executes the function? This is impossible.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: OK, but that's not exactly intuitive behavior, is it?  Is there a Pythonic way to get out of this morass?  Maybe not put a `yield` inside an `if` that will never execute?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I would suggest not using `return` and `yield` in the same function if you can avoid it. In a generator, `return` means "stop generating". In a normal function, `return` means "return this value". You may consider it unintuitive, but I would consider everything in programming to be unintuitive. It would surprise me greatly if Python would somehow change whether a function was a generator function based on the execution path of the function... clearly our intuition for these things is different.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail. I learned something new - I can't make a decorator which applies both to a generator and non-generator.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov: You can make a decorator which applies to both, see the solution in my answer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I assume you mean to make a decorator which includes ```wrapper``` which returns ```wrap_generator``` when the function is a generator, instead of checking it with an if. I agree, I can do that, but I meant that I can't put all this code in a single decorator function body. Or could I?

Comment: @NikolayShindarov: Why does it matter if you can put all the code in a single function body or not? Your `decor` decorator already consists of two different functions, and there is no harm in adding a third function.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Of course it doesn't matter, I just loved the concept of compact code related to decorators that's why I would like it even more if I could do it in a single function. I actually thought I need to put your second function outside of the decorator, but just tested it and found out it works also with both functions inside the generators, so that seems cool enough. Thanks also for putting in the ```types``` check, seems more reliable.